# transform a rdf to rdf schema(rdfs)

Tags: rdf, rdfs

so i have a a rdf representation of a two restaurents and i want to tranform both of them in a rdf schema (rdfs) .
the first one is an italien restaurent :

```
    xml version=‘1.0’>
  <rdf:RDFXmlns:rdf=‘http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#’
    Xmlns: resto= ‘http://www.restaurants.com/vocabulary#’>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘http://www.restaurants.com/italien#pizzeria’>
    <resto:Est_un> restaurant</ex:Est>
    <resto:de_specialite> pizza</ex:A>
    <resto:serve>
    <rdf :Bag>
    <rdf :bag>
    <rdf :li>pizza</rdf :li>
    <rdf :li>pasta</rdf :li>
    </rdf :bag>
    <rdf :bag>
    <rdf :li>tiramuso</rdf :li>
    <rdf :li>cappucino</rdf :li>
    </rdf :bag>
    </rdf :bag>
    </resto:serve>
    <resto:propose>Formul</resto:propose>
    <resto:appartient_a>italy</resto:appartient_a>
    </rdf: Description>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #formule>
    <resto:propose>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #complete>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #Dishes>
    <resto :contain>
    <rdf :seq>
    <rdf :li>Entrance</rdf :li>
    <rdf :li>PrincipalDishe</rdf :li>
    <rdf :li>dessert</rdf :li>
    </rdf :seq>
    </resto :contain>
    </rdf :description>
    </rdf :description>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #Menu>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
    <resto :contain>Principaldishe</resto :contient>
    </rdf :description>
    </rdf :description>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #midday>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
    <resto :contain>PrincipalDishe</resto :contient>
    </rdf :description>
    </rdf :description>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #snack>
    <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
    <resto :contain>
    <rdf :bag>
    <rdf :li>drink</rdf :li>
    <rdf :li>dessert</rdf :li>
    </rdf :bag>
        </resto :contain>
        </rdf :description>
        </rdf :description>
        <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #gastronomie>
        <rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
        <resto :contient>plat</resto :contain>
        </rdf :description>
        </rdf :description>
        </resto:propose>
        </rdf :description>
```

And the second one it is a japonnais restaurent :

```
<?xml version=‘1.0’>
<rdf:RDFXmlns:rdf=‘http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#’
Xmlns: resto= ‘http://www.restaurants.com/vocabulary#’>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘http://www.restaurants.com/japon#sushibar’>
<resto:Est_un> restaurant</resto :est_un>
<resto:de_speciality> sushi </resto :de_speciality>
<resto:serve>
<rdf :Bag>
<rdf :bag>
<df :li>Ramen</rdf :li>
<rdf :li>sushi</rdf :li>
<rdf :li>Teriyaki</rdf :li>
</rdf :bag>
</resto:serve>
<resto:propose>Formule</resto:propose>
<resto:appartient_a> japon</resto:appartient_a>
</rdf: Description>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #formule>
<resto:propose>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #complet>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
<resto :contain>
<rdf :seq>
<rdf :li> Entrance</rdf :li>
<rdf :li> PrincipalDishe</rdf :li>
<rdf :li>dessert</rdf :li>
</rdf :seq>
</resto :contain>
</rdf :description>
</rdf :description>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #Menu>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
<resto :contient>PlatPrincipal</resto :contain>
</rdf :description>
</rdf :description>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #midi>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
<resto :contain>PrincipalDishe</resto :contain>
</rdf :description>
</rdf :description>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #snack>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
<resto :contain>
<rdf :bag>
<rdf :li>drink</rdf :li>
<rdf :li>dessert</rdf :li>
</rdf :bag>
</resto :contain>
</rdf :description>
</rdf :description>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #gastronomie>
<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=‘rsto #dishes>
<resto :contient>plat</resto :contain>
</rdf :description>
</rdf :description>
</resto:propose>
</rdf :description>
</rdf:description>
```

any help or just hints are really appreciated ans sorry if my question is dump i'm just beginner in the semantic web

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean with "transform" here. What would you like this RDF Schema to look like?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra sorry for the the late response but i'm gonna try to describe my ontology briefly so i have a two restaurets every restaurent provide some formules and every formules include some dishes but evry restaurent has a one main dishe and i want to make rdf schema(rdfs) if you want more inforamtion you can visit this link when yuo will find the uml class diagram of one of the restaurnts https://app.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/26df2077-5798-414c-8183-4a59ecaef5a1